# How to pull all objects from an array of unknown length and place them into a state variable in React?

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I imported data from another file (so I technically think it's an object containing an array of objects) called { groupData }. At the moment, the array contains only 5 objects, but it is variable in length and could contain more. Each object looks like this:

```
{
  name: "A Name",
  img: "https://imgURL.goes.here",
  details: "This is a fun group about fun things.",
  likes: 45,
},
```

My goal is to take each object from the array, modify the data, and place the objects into an empty stateful array called "groups". I want each object to look like this before it goes into the new "groups" array:

```
{
  name: "A Name",
  img: "https://imgURL.goes.here",
  details: "This is a fun group about fun things.",
  hasNotification: Boolean,
  userIsAdmin: Boolean,
},
```

I thought of destructuring the array, but this solution is not scalable if things are going to be added to the array:

```
const [groupZero, groupOne, groupTwo, groupThree, groupFour] = groupData;
```

What is the most efficient way to accomplish this? Thank you!!

Comment: does it matter if the property of the original objects in groupData changes?

Comment: No, I don't think it would matter if the original properties change, as long as the values are still there and accessible, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you need because of the lack of context. But you can use a for loop to iterate through each object in the array.

If it is fine to moderate the existing data:

```
for (data of groupData){
  delete data.likes;
  data.hasNotification = true; // or false
  data.userIsAdmin = true; // or false
}

setState(groupData); // if you are using useState hooks
```

If you do not want to change original data:

```
// create a deep clone of groupData
const newGroup = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(groupData));

for (data of newGroup){
  delete data.likes;
  data.hasNotification = true; // or false
  data.userIsAdmin = true; // or false
}

setState(newGroup);
```

Adjust the setState section accordingly if you are using class components